# table with a Date column in DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: sql-server

I have an excel source with a date column in dd/mm/yyyy format. I need to load a table with data from this source in exactly the same format. using just DATE data type gives me output of yyyy-mm-dd. So how do I store it in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Why do you need to store the data in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. You can store the data in default format. If you need this format to display you can simply use `convert` function.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about how the data is stored. Let the native DATE type do its thing. Use the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function to format your data for display purposes.

```
/* 103 = dd/mm/yyyy */
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), YourDateColumn, 103) AS formatted_date
    FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: it's a requirement that it has to be stored in the table in the exact same format as it is in the source

Comment: @mish That is a nonsense requirement. When you give your car to a valet, you don't dictate exactly how and where he should park it. As long as he takes it and returns it to you in the condition you expect, then the how and where of the actual parking are irrelevant to you.